# Number of occurrences of the digit 1 in the numbers from 0 to n

Tags: c#, math

i need help in console application that take a number 
then calculate the amount of occurrences of number 1

it's the mathematical solution

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47477/number-of-occurrences-of-the-digit-1-in-the-numbers-from-0-to-n

i tried to implement this function but i'm not lucky in cause of math miss-understanding

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number");
        string num =Console.ReadLine();
        s.Start();
        int count = 0;
        int[] numbers = new int [num.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
        { 
            numbers[i] = Int32.Parse( num.Substring(num.Length - 1 - i, 1))*(Int32)Math.Pow(10,i);
        }

        int digits;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            digits = numbers[i].ToString().Length-1;
            Int32 lastDegit = Int32.Parse(numbers[i].ToString()[0]+"");
            count+=Convert.ToInt32(lastDegit*digits*Math.Pow(10, digits-1));

      //i'm not sure about next line
      count += Convert.ToInt32(lastDegit * (numbers[i].ToString().Length - 1) * Math.Pow(10, numbers[i].ToString().Length - 2));

        }

        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
```

i have a problem with the term i commented befor

Comment: What line exactly are you having problems on?

Comment: @itsme86 It appears to be the second to last line (the `Convert`) one

Comment: A shorter solution might be: `Enumerable.Range(0, n + 1).Select(v => v.ToString().Count(c => c == '1')).Sum();` :)

Comment: lol except for the fact that is not the "mathematical" solution at all heh. @itsme86

Comment: @austinwernli What do you mean? There's a `Sum()` in there!

Comment: smells like homework ...

Comment: @itsme86 this line
count += Convert.ToInt32(lastDegit * (numbers[i].ToString().Length - 1) * Math.Pow(10, numbers[i].ToString().Length - 2));
the problem is how to implement the algorithm in link

Comment: @rupps yep :D
also we have the permission to search or ask any way

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Join(string.Empty, Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)).Count(x => x == '1')
```

(where n = 1000)

Comment: This gives a solution, not an answer. Besides, there's no point in using `String.Join` passing `String.Empty` as the delimiter, use `String.Concat` instead.

Comment: this solution takes a lot also in large number it fires outOfMemoryException